# "GetSizeForItem" for a UICollectionView in Xamarin with UICollectionViewFlowLayout does not get called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UICollectionView` added as a subview in the viewDidLoad. I am using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and have created a custom `MvxCollectionViewSource` to manage the cells.

I provide the cell information in the constructor of the layout object which does not make it flexible for device and orientation changes.

```
UICollectionViewLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout () {ItemSize = new SizeF (354, 150),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
        };
```

Allocating my UICollectionView in the ViewDidLoad method.

```
CollectionView = new UICollectionView (this.View.Bounds, layout);
        CollectionView.Delegate = new CustomViewDelegate();
        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(ProjectCollectionCell), ProjectCollectionCell.Key);
        CollectionView.Source = new ProjectCollectionSource (CollectionView, this,ProjectCollectionCell.Key);
        CollectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        //          CollectionView.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView (typeof(Header), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, headerId);
        CollectionView.AllowsMultipleSelection = true;
        this.View.AddSubview (CollectionView);
```

Now the ProjectCollectionSource is my custom source and have created a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800733/257284).

The `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` is as below but it never gets called.

```
class CustomViewDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    {

        public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return new CoreGraphics.CGSize (100, 100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've got a small demo for collection view on Github - maybe it helps you to identify the problem? https://github.com/Krumelur/QuickAndDirtyCollViewDemo

Comment: @Krumelur +1 You demo app did help me with my problem. I was setting my custom source to the UICollectionView "Source" but when I set it to the collectionview "data source", it started working.